# Is possible to create code in Delphi for Android for devices based on Intel Atom?

Tags: android, delphi, intel

Is possible to create code in Delphi 10 Seattle for Android for devices based on Intel Atom?

Comment: Hmm, voting irregularities. Not cool.

Comment: Intel Atom is a different answer than ARM7 NEON. Delphi apps run on Intel Atom devices running Android 4.4+ through libHoudini which ships with Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docwiki.embarcadeo.com](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development):

> ARM instruction CPUs are created by a wide variety of manufacturers
>   according to different sets of specifications. ARM is the dominant
>   technology in mobile hardware. The ARMv7 instruction set, or core,
>   specifies the microarchitecture that the CPU uses. The family of CPUs
>   that implement ARMv7 instructions are called the Cortex-A series. Most
>   of these CPUs also include NEON technology. Some Android devices
>   instead use the Intel ATOM architecture, which is incompatible with
>   FireMonkey. The reason RAD Studio applications require this specific
>   CPU architecture is that RAD Studio apps compile down to machine code
>   for best performance. This is different than other Android apps that
>   are developed with Java that compile down to Dalvik bytecode and then
>   run on the Dalvik virtual machine. Most Android devices have a GPU, or
>   Graphics Processing Unit. It is common for the GPU to be combined with
>   the CPU in a System-on-a-Chip (or SoC) configuration. Any of these
>   configurations should be supported.

Comment: You did not please me, but nevertheless thank you for the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing can be done.

Comment: Embarcadero has no plans to support it. See https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=115276

Comment: There is no other than write code in Java ...

Comment: Who is David Heffeman?

Comment: I do not know who it is. Try to look at his profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan

Answer (score 1):

I tried, but really this code can not run on Android device with Intel Atom processor